# VBA doesn't return the correct Date with Now()

Tags: vba, excel, date

I have a simple code and VBA cannot return the correct date:

```
Sub Test_Date ()

Debug.Print Format(Month(Now()), "mmm")
Debug.Print Month(Now())
Debug.Print Now()

End Sub
```

Returns:

```
Dez
 1 
29.01.2018 11:17:55
```

1) Is that an Excel well known issue or did I make a mistake?

Comment: You made a mistake by using both `Format` and `Month`. You just want: `Debug.Print Format(Now(), "mmm")`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is a known issue. And it is actually not an issue.

In `Debug.Print Format(Month(Now()), "mmm")` you are passing
`Debug.Print Format(1,"mmm")`.

And the first day in VBA is `31.12.1899`. And its month is `December`. Run this small piece of code to see it:

```
Sub TestMe()
    Debug.Print Format(1, "dd-mmm-yyyy")
End Sub
```

---

If you want the month of the current date - `Format(Now, "mmm")`

---

In general, be a bit careful, when you are working with dates in Excel, VBA and MSSQL Server. The dates are converted to numbers. E.g., every date is converted to a number, but the starting number can be a bit different.

- In Excel, the `1` is converted to `01.January.1900`;
- In VBA, the `1` is converted to `31.December.1899`;
- In MSSQL Server, the `1` is converted to `02.January.1900` (`SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME,1)`);
- In Excel, if you activate the `ActiveWorkbook.Date1904=True` property, the `1` is converted to `02.January.1904`;

The reason for this is an error, made by the creators of Lotus 1-2-3, who have thought that 29.02.1900 was a valid date. Thus, Excel wanted to become compatible with Lotus 1-2-3 and they have carried on with this error. In VBA, they have decided not to implement the error, thus the dates in VBA and Excel are a bit different, but this is only for the period up to 1. March 1900 - [MSDN date explanation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/214330/differences-between-the-1900-and-the-1904-date-system-in-excel).

Thus, depending on which one of the 4 "environments" above you are working, today's date (29-January-2018) can be converted to one of the following:

- 41667 (Excel with Date1904)
- 43128 (MSSQL Server `SELECT CONVERT(INT, CONVERT(DATETIME,GETDATE()))`)
- 43129 (Excel)
- 43129 (VBA)

If you take the 35. day and convert it to date in Excel, VBA and MSSQL Server, the result will be as follows:

- 03.February.1900 (VBA)
- 04.February.1900 (Excel)
- 05.February.1900 (MSSQL Server - `SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME,35)`)
- 05.February.1904 (Excel with Date1904)

---

This article (written by the owner of SO) gives some addition enlightment:
[My First BillG Review](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2006/06/16/my-first-billg-review/)