# How to display only year in vba?

Tags: excel, vba, date

I have the following data set in general formatting.

[image]

Bunch of years with no day nor months provided.
What I want to achieve, **is to display the date in `yyyy` format**.

I made a standard `DateSerial` function to convert the data to date properly.

```
Private Function toDate(ByVal text As String) As Date
    toDate = DateSerial(Int(text), 1, 1)
End Function

For Each cell in ws.Range("A21:A" & lr)
    cell = toDate(cell)
    cell.NumberFormat = "yyyy"
Next cell
```

> Now, technically this works, but if you click inside the cell, it
>   obviously shows the date only as `01-01-year` - that is to be expected
>   with usage of dateserial
>
> [image]
>
> [image: enter image descriptionhere]
>
> But I was wondering, would it be possible given my data to somehow
>   omit the `Days` and `Months` and only display the result as a `year`?

**Basically, I need want to convert the data to a `Date` data-type without specifying days and months**

Comment: What's the end goal here?  If you always want them displayed as xxxx even when the user clicks to edit, why not just us xxxx ?

Comment: @TimWilliams Sadly, this was requested specifically to be in `yyyy` format. I personally would have also preferred to leave it as a simple number, but not my choice here :)

Comment: I guess, the question could have been shortened to a simple **"Is it possible to create a `Date` data-type without day and month"**, but you know, "having to show your effort and all that" being applied

Comment: I would guess the answer is No, and that if it's important for the list to stay as xxxx then conversion to a date should occur when the values are consumed/used.

Comment: You can do with Excel formula + change Number Format. Say your Year series is A1, then in B1: `=DATE(A1,1,1)`, fill down and you are done, then change number format both A:B columns to **`yyyy`**. Then Copy paste value from B to A, get rid of column B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entering the years and formatting the date as "YYYY"  could be done like this:

```
Sub TestMe()

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
        .Range("A1") = 2011
        .Range("A2") = 2013
        .Range("A3") = 2011

        Dim myCell As Range
        For Each myCell In .Range("A1:A3")
            myCell = DateSerial(myCell, 1, 1)
            myCell.NumberFormat = "yyyy"
        Next myCell
    End With

End Sub
```

The "trick", is that `DateSerial(myCell, 1, 1)` takes the year from the cell and adds `1` for day and January for month. Thus, every year is represented as the date 1.January from that year.

More about the `Date` in VBA and Excel - [VBA doesn't return the correct Date with Now()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48498998/vba-doesnt-return-the-correct-date-with-now)

Comment: I think the issue is that they want only "2011", "2013", or "2011" to appear in the formula bar when a user selects the cell, instead of "m-d-yyyy".

Comment: As @dwirony pointed out above ^ ... I guess i'll remove the 1905 part as it's just useless clutter in the question

Comment: @Rawrplus - well, the easiest way I can think of is to use the formula `=YEAR(A1)` and put `01.01.2011` in A1.

Comment: @Vityata yeah I guess that kinda *hides* the day and month. I'll leave the question open to see if anyone comes up with anything, but yeah, most likely it is not possible to omit day and motnh out of the date